# using 'owe' in passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

We can say:

He owes an apology to us.

We can't say:

An apology is owed to us.

We can say:

We're owed an apology.

Can we say:

We're owed an apology by him?

Comment: Why do you think you can't say 'An apology is owed to us'?

Comment: @ Michael Woke Harvey
 because of this   https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/owe?q=owe

Comment: Where does it say you can't say 'An apology is owed to us'?

Comment: in the entry number 2

Comment: That is one dictionary. Proceedings of the Australian parliament "This is not just an issue where **an apology is owed to us**, to the committee or to the Assembly; this is an apology that is required to the community, who have been waiting since December on an answer".

Answer (score 3):

> He owes an apology to us.

I think we would normally say *He owes us an apology*

> An apology is owed to us.

That is perfectly fine but would not be as common as the active way.

> We're owed an apology.

That is fine

> We're owed an apology by him?

That sounds a bit contrived as the active is shorter and more direct but it is not wrong.